# When compiling makefile project in Visual Studio Express 2012, the .exe does not work in Windows Server 2003

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2012, makefile, 32bit-64bit

As an extension on one of my earlier projects that required printing PDF files from command line, I now need to print them duplex.

Therefore I have found an open source piece of software called SumatraPDF and added a patch using Visual Studio Express 2012 that enables duplex settings in command line and compiled. This software works completely on Windows 7 64bit however on Windows Server 2003 64bit it returns an error message:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I have found examples on the internet of others having this issue when compiling applications using VSE2012 and have tried to follow the advice given. This being to change the project platform to `Windows XP (v110_xp)` after installing VS Service Pack 3, however to do this I would have to change the project configuration type from `Makefile` to `Application (.exe)` and after testing this causes errors during compilation.

I have now also implemented @Hans advice with the same result.

If anyone can help I would be most appreciative.

Thanks.

NB - I have looked at other questions regarding this subject and did not feel any supplied me with a solution, apologies if I have overlooked it.

Comment: You will have to make the changes in the makefile, the IDE settings cannot have any effect.  The linker's /SUBSYSTEM option needs to be used to set the major,minor version back to 5,0

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant. I have found the following line in the `makefile.msvc` that relates to your advice:
    
`$(ENGINEDUMP_APP): $(ENGINEDUMP_OBJS)
 $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $** $(LIBS) /PDB:$*.pdb /OUT:$@ /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE`

Would you be able to further clarify what requires changing?

Comment: So make it /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE,5.0

Comment: Though this has compiled successfully, it unfortunately has not solved my issue of not being able to open the application in Windows Server 2003 64bit. Any other ideas?

Comment: Any more ideas @HansPassant?